# Strange behaviour from MySQL in Powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and have a specific question about working with MySQL in PowerShell.

I got this function:

```
Function run-mySQLInsertQuery{
    param(
        $connection,
        [string[]]$insertQuery
    )
    foreach ($command in $insertQuery){
        $MySQLCommand = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $MySQLCommand.CommandText = $command
        $rowsInserted = $MySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        if ($rowsInserted) {
            return $rowsInserted
        } else {
            return $false
        }
    }
}
```

With this version of the function i get the following Error:

```
Cause:
"The CommandText property has not been properly initialized."

Errorline:
        $rowsInserted = $MySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I searched for a solution and edited my function a bit to the following (for testing purpose):

```
Function run-mySQLInsertQuery{
    param(
        $connection,
        [string[]]$insertQuery
    )
    $abcd = $insertQuery[1]
    foreach ($command in $insertQuery){
        $MySQLCommand = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $MySQLCommand.CommandText = $abcd
        $rowsInserted = $MySQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
}
```

With this code, the function executes the query without a problem. My question now is, why? i cant really see a difference, because in `$command` should be the exact same query like it is in `$abcd`. Or am I getting something wrong?

**EDIT:**
As its asked it the comments, here is how i call the function:

```
[String[]]$statements = ""

foreach($key in $arrayStatus.Keys){
    $item = $arrayStatus[$key]
    $insertStatus = "INSERT INTO tx_tphbusinessofferings_domain_model_status (status_id, status) VALUES ('$key', '$item')"
    $statements += $insertStatus
}
$Rows = run-mySQLInsertQuery -connection $mySQLconnection -insertQuery $statements
```

Comment: So in your edited function - you are running the _first_ `insertQuery` value multiple times. This suggests that the problem is within the _other_ insertQuery values...

Comment: How are you calling your function? Can you show an example of the parameters that are failing?

Comment: @Jcl I've edited my question and show how I call the function!

Comment: @gvee I don't think this is the problem, because im looping through an array with the values i want to insert. Im only changing the values and not the query itself, as you can see in the edit i made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are initializing your array (the one you are passing in) with an empty string:

```
[String[]]$statements = ""
```

And then adding elements to it... so your first iteration of the passed array is an empty string, which won't work (it'll set the command text as empty, that's the error you are getting). It works on the second code because you are grabbing the second object of the array (which is your insert statement).

Initialize your array to empty and it should work:

```
[String[]]$statements = @()
```

Apart from that, your first script always returns on the first iteration, so it'll only work once (not for every `insert` you pass). Not sure what do you want to return if you are passing in more than one query, but that's up to your design decisions

Comment: Thank you very much! Now its working like a charm :-)